# Override Default PAM Message Prompt

Tags: pam

I'm using a YubiKey for ssh 2 factor authentication. I've directed the flow to `pam.d/ssh` and added the provided `pam_yubico.so` module.

I would like to override the default prompt which displays:

> YubiKey for `user`

[This](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/) page, indicates that `pam_yubico` has no module parameters that support overriding the default message prompt.

[This](https://github.com/firnsy/yubipam) github project seems to have written a wrapper that supports a `discrete_prompt` parameter flag.

I would like to stick to the manufacturer's PAM module for security reasons.

Is there anyway to override that message or is the only way to modify the source and recompile the PAM library?